# HTML5 & CSS Header banner image and text alignment

Tags: css, html, http-headers, background-image

I've been trying to put a banner image behind a text in the top header but the formatting just doesn't seem to work out.
I also tried `background-image: url(/imgs/header_pic.jpg);` in the stylesheet but that way it doesn't even show up. Currently it shows up, behind the text, image can't be centered or resized for a max height and the navigation (the list items) are also overlapping the image.

```css
div#header-background {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 4em;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10%;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

h1#header-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="header-background"><img src="imgs/header_pic.jpg"></div>
    <h1 id="header-text">John Doe</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
      <li><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:** After checking the answers (thank you!). I did a little research and modified it to the following code. Now I only need to move the text vertically to the center because it's weirdly not perfectly centered but off a bit. 
What do you guys think?

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 12em;
    position: relative;
  }

h1#header-text{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
header:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(imgs/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're currently doing it, you can hide the overflow by adding this to your CSS:

```css
div#header-background{
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 4em;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 10%;
    opacity: 0.25;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0xwbq73/2/

To apply background-image, you can do it like this:

```css
header{
    background-image: url('https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

h1#header-text{ 
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <h1 id="header-text">John Doe</h1>
</header>
    <nav>
       <ul style="list-style-type: none">
          <li><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

However, you won't be able to control the opacity of the image by CSS, so you'd have to do it through Photoshop, or other image editor.

https://jsfiddle.net/5g1zjLhw/

You can check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp for more info on positioning/sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Im new at web design but I would like to help you solve your issue if I can. I believe your problem is that you did not define the size of image. I copied your code and input width and height values for the image and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#header-background {
  background-image:url('imgs/header_pic.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
h1#header-text{
  text-align:center;
}
ui li{
  text-decoration:non;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header-background">
    <h1 id="header-text">John Doe</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```